# How to deserialize ResponseEntity for Redis?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am creating a custom cache schema in my organization and am having to serialize ResponseEntity objects. I am using GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer to serialize the objects, however when it is the ResponseEntity it does not accept.

My custom redis template with the Jackson Serializer:

```
 @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new CustomRedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
```

My endpoint returning the ResponseEntity:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public ResponseEntity<String> foo() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("bar", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Log of error:

```
Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: [B@74297a01; line: 1, column: 137] (through reference chain: br.com.stilingue.cloudutilities.cache.CacheItem["value"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: [B@74297a01; line: 1, column: 137] (through reference chain: br.com.stilingue.cloudutilities.cache.CacheItem["value"])
```

The problem occurs at the time of deserialize the object, does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: I have this same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: unfortunately no :/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding type info in return statement:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>("bar", HttpStatus.OK);
```